# how to prevent vertical scroll bar in an owner drawn combo box when only 3 items exists?

Tags: visual-c++, combobox, mfc

I sub-classed a combo-box control to make text vertically centred. Issue here is I am getting a vertical scroll bar when only 3 or 4 items exists in the combo-box that too when I expand the control for the first time, where a vertical scroll is not required.

Control property had been set as follows.

```
COMBOBOX IDC_COMBOBOX,28,45,205,65,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_OWNERDRAWNFIXED | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP.
```

When I removed `WS_VSCROLL` vertical scroll bar is not coming. But if I remove this property I will not get a scroll bar when too many items exists in the combobox, where actually a scroll is required.

Please find the below Images for your reference how the control is behaving.

Run the MFC application.

Expand the combobox.
[image]

Again try expanding the combo box issue is not reproducing. It's happening only
for the very first time when expand the control.
[image]

I could not figure out why this issue is happening. I tried removing the existing control and again I tried adding new controls expecting whether it could bring any change in the behaviour but no luck.

Item height is set to 30 as below.

```
m_ComboBox.SetItemHeight(-1, 30);
```

And I had two combobox controls in my properysheet application as shown in the image.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The height of the combobox includes the space for the drop-down. Just make it taller, either by adjusting the height in resource file, or programmatically at runtime. Apparently, 65 is not enough.

Comment: Even though I increased the height same result happening. I have same control in other pages where I am not getting this issue. What I noticed was if I place another combo box control where it is working fine there issue is reproducing. I could not get like why it is reproducing if there are two combo box in one page. It should not be the issue right?

Comment: Is it because of subclassing is not done properly?